# Detecting app tamper with signature using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I was able to detect the app tampering using the android code snippet and working fine for locally distributed production build. But after uploading in to Playstore getting different app signature. Any advice you could give would be much appreciated

```
//get the current app signature
  public static String getCurrentAppSignature(Context context) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    // Get the first signature from the package info.
    Signature signature = packageInfo.signatures[0];
    // Get the SHA-1 hash of the signature.
    byte[] sha1 = getSHA1(signature.toByteArray());
    // Convert the SHA-1 hash to a string.
    String sha1String = convertToHexString(sha1);
    return sha1String;
  }

  //get the SHA1 hash
  private static byte[] getSHA1(byte[] data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    digest.update(data);
    return digest.digest();
  }

  //convert to HexString
  private static String convertToHexString(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : data) {
      sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```